# WITH query (postgres) on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Postgres has great support for [WITH queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

I wonder if I can somehow us WITH operation on active record?

Something like:

```
User.with("user_sales as (select user_id, sum(amount) from sales)")
    .joins("LEFT JOIN user_sales on users.id = user_sales.user_id"
```

I know that I could achieve the same without WITH query, however queries usually becomes way more complicated without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arel`, the engine below `ActiveRecord` defines several useful methods, including the WITH query.

```
User.joins('...').tap do |relation|
  relation.arel.with(Sale.select('...').arel.as('user_sales'))
end
```

However, do be aware that `Arel` is officially considered private api and subject to change.

Just make sure you do all of your `ActiveRecord` things before `.arel`